# Sort on a Ref<?> attribute - Objectify Query

Tags: sorting, objectify

I am struck in a data operation where I want to sort results of a query by a Ref field.

Lets say I have the following Data Objects.

1. EmployeeDO {Long id, String name, Ref refCompany}
2. CompanyDO {Long id, String name}

Now i want to query employees arranged by company name.

I tried the query

```
Query<EmployeeDO> query = ofy().load().type(EmployeeDO.class).order("refCompany");
```

Obviously this did not sort results with company name, but this compiled successfully too.

Please suggest if such sorting is possible by this way or some other workaround can be tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by refCompany if you @Index refCompany, but it won't sort by company name - it will index by the key (if you aren't using @Parent, just an id order).

There are two 'usual' choices:

- Load the data into ram and sort there. This is what an RDBMS would do internally. It's not exactly true that GAE doesn't support joins; it's just that you're the query planner.
- Denormalize and pre-index the companyName. Put `@Index companyName` in the EmployeeDO. This is what you would do with an RDBMS if you the magic sorting performed poorly (say, there are too many employees).

Comment: Thank you! I did it the second way you have suggested. It works, just that I have to update the "Denormalized-pre-index companyName in employeeDO" every time the company name is updated or employee changes her company. I was wondering if there was some way I could sort on a ref attribute:Name field directly. That would have been ideal.